# How many homomorphisms are there from one group to another group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

In our lecture we were asked to answer the following questions:

How many are there homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ to $S_{3}$? And vice-versa?

How many are there homomorphisms from $S_{3}$ to $Q_{8}$? And vice-versa?

I am a little confused about it. I know from the definition of a homomorphism that it is a map from one group to another such that the group operation is preserved. But how am I supposed to find one between two groups?

I know the group  $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ is $(0,0), (1,1), (1,0), (0,1)$ and the symmetric group $(1), (12), (13), (132), (123)$ but how do I know which elements to map to which elements?

Am I supposed to look at underlying properties of the groups? Such as whether it is abelian or not, or whether or not it is a cyclic group? And then compare generators? Could someone explain this concept to me using the above question?

Comment: Try to use 1st isomporphism theorem. check possible kernel.

Comment: A useful thing to remember is that order of elements must be "preserved", i.e. if $x$ has order $n$ then $f(x)$ must have order dividing $n$ (here $f$ is a homomorphism, $x$ an element of the domain).

Comment: @Dave An answer would be really appreciated!

Comment: @SwapnajitDas An answer would be really appreciated1

Comment: You will get more help if you make a serious attempt to solve the problem yourself - you appear not to have tried at all.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't understand how to even start. How do I define a homomorphism? Let alone count them?

Comment: Hint: a homomorphism is uniquely determined by where it sends generators. Can you see why this is true? And, can you see how to use this fact to systematically count them in you cases above?

Comment: Hey @DerekAllums, I will think about this some more tomorrow. But a thought: aren't generators only for cyclic groups? What if the group is not cyclic?

Comment: @Anonymous Every group has generators; cyclic groups have exactly one.

Comment: Actually @DerekAllums, could you expand on that a little bit more? Why are homomorphisms uniquely determined by where it sends its generators?

Comment: I think you should start by trying a few specific maps from the first group to the second and checking whether they are homomorphisms. You should quickly discover that the identity must map to the identity, for example. Ultimately you can only learn to solve problems by trying to do so.

Comment: Regarding "how to start", here's a reality check: Do you understand how to write down a *function* from the set $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ to the set $S_3$? Do you know how to explain *how many* such functions there are?

Comment: @LeeMosher So THAT is exactly where I am confused. When people define homomorphisms/isomorphisms, they say "let's say there's a function", but the choice of function seems so arbitrary to me. So I guess I don't understand how to write a function from one set to the other? How do I know, which elements to send to which elements?

Comment: You can know that in many different ways. In calculus, a function is often known by giving a formula. In finite set theory, a function is often known by literally writing down each input value from the domain and the corresponding output value from the range. In finite group theory, a homomorphism between finite groups could also be given by literally writing down each input value from the domain group and the corresponding output value from the range group (subject to the constraint that the homomorphism "preserves products").

Comment: But the main point is that to write down a group homomorphism there's a shortcut: you only need to write down the outputs for each individual input generator; you can then compute the outputs for every other input element as long as that element is given to you as a product of generators (there is still a constraint regarding relators, but I think the main point has been made).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**: homomorphisms are determined by where they send generators.

**Explanation**: Let $\phi:X \to Y$ be a homomorphism, where $X = \langle x_1,\ldots, x_n \rangle$. The above hint means that if another homomorphism $\psi$ sends all the $x_i$ to the same place in $Y$, then $\phi \equiv \psi$ identically. To see this, take any arbitrary element $x \in X$. Then $x =\prod x_i$ is some finite product of generators. So $$\phi(x) = \phi \left( \prod x_i \right) = \prod \phi(x_i) = \prod \psi(x_i) = \psi\left(\prod x_i\right) = \psi(x)$$
That is, $\phi$ and $\psi$ act identically on $x$. Said another way, they are the same. And yet another way: homomorphisms are determined by how they act on generators. This + the hint from @Dave on preserving order should take you far since the example groups are small.

**Hint 2**: using the first isomoprhism theorem will help count as well since you know a homomorphism gives you a kernel, and that kernel is a subgroup of your domain. How many subgroups are there? Are each a possible kernel?

Comment: Could you explain why homomorphisms are determined by where they send generators?

Comment: This is exactly what I am describing in the first extended hint.